# How to fetch field value from standard output (stdout) in python?

Tags: python, stdout

I am trying to fetch a value from the standard output in python. This is the command I run from the command line to list firewalls in the GKE cluster.

```sh
gcloud compute firewall-rules list \
  --project <myproject> \
  --filter="name~gke-cluster-123456789*"
```

When the command is executed on a bastion server the output is like:

```
NAME                      NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         DENY  DISABLED
gke-cluster-XXX-all  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp,udp,XXX                         False
gke-cluster-XXX-ssh  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:XX                              False
gke-cluster-XXX-vms  default  INGRESS    1000      icmp,tcp:1-XXXXX,udp:1-XXXXX        False
```

I need to do the same in python but only fetching the name field. However, the code below, fetchs the firewall name along with **NAME** Label.

**Part of my code**

```py
cmd = gcloud compute firewall-rules list --project <myproject> --filter="name~gke-cluster-123456789*"
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
   print(line.split()[0])
```

Actual Output:

```
NAME
gke-cluster-XXX-all
gke-cluster-XXX-ssh
gke-cluster-XXX-vms
```

Expected Output: (What I need is)

```
gke-cluster-XXX-all
gke-cluster-XXX-ssh
gke-cluster-XXX-vms
```

How do I remove the first line of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using gcloud alone:

```sh
gcloud compute firewall-rules list \
--filter=${FILTER} \
--format="value[no-heading](name)" \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats

Answer (score 2):

```
for index, line in enumerate(text.splitlines()):
    if index != 0:
        print(line.split()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you can also handle the line skip at the bash command line:

```sh
python <script> | tail -n +2
```